# Matching SUMIFS Criteria on cell string value

Tags: excel, dataframe

I want to add the values in Column G of Master tab, if column D = "Outcome 1", and column J equals cell A3 in current sheet. I'm using this formula below.

`=SUMIFS(Master!G:G,Master!D:D,"Outcome 1",['Master'!J:J, A3])`

Any tips? Thank you!

Comment: and what is that formula doing that is in error.  the `[]` should not be there.

Comment: something like `=SUMIFS(Master!G:G,Master!D:D,"Outcome 1",Master!J:J, $A$3)` should work.

Comment: Thank you! I realized the syntax excel was suggesting was not to be taken literally. This worked.